# Possible to get a return of a whole Java program like Python scripts?

Tags: java, python, cmd, return

Question as above.

I could need it for testautomation, Python gives you the opportunity to return a value at the end of a def.

When I searched in google about the same for java, I found out that a Main method is not able to be decleared as a String or int.

Is there a way to get a return of a whole Java Program runned with command line?

Short: I want a return output of a variable at the end of a program, like I would use return in a class

Example for Python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
math = 1+1
return math
```

I know, what I showed is also possible in Java CLASSES, but at the end I need it for a whole java program, in python I have the opportunity to run a whole script and get an output(returnvalue) of this script

Comment: Can you please give more details in your question?

Comment: Could you provide a short example of what you mean in terms of Python?

Comment: I want a return output of a variable at the end of a program, like I would use return in a class

Comment: you could run a java program or call a method in a java program from a python script.there are lot of libraries for this kind of support. you can google a bit on that

Comment: Yes I could, but its a testautomation programm, I need it as a whole not a single class

Comment: What you seem to mean, is called [exit status](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status), therefore, [`System.exit`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#Java).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `System.exit()` almost exactly like the `exit()` function in C.

```
public class MyApp {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.exit(123);
    }
}
```

Whatever integer value `System.exit()` emits will be transmitted to the calling shell. The value should be between 0 and 255 for Unix/Linux shells. After your program exits, you can:

```
echo $?
```

to see the value of the return/exit code. For the program above, that would be 123.

Comment: Does System.exit() not just return 0 and 1?

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit(int)) the exit value (return value to the shell) is an `int`. 0 and 1 are classical return values, 0 for "correct termination" and 1 for "improper termination," but other values may also be returned.